# How we replace new line to $$

Tags: shell, unix, hive

I need to replace newline `\n` with `$$` in hive script or by using shell script. I need to make each single record in single row i.e example

```
Ram is going to temple.Shyam is going to the temple.
```

Here "Ram is going to temple." should be single line

line only break once record end, if line break in between make it in single line.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\$\$/g;s/\./\.\n/g' datafile > outputfile
```

if sed knows option i, you can use inplace

```
sed -i ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\$\$/g;s/\./\.\n/g' datafile
```

Comment: original
abc \n
def \n
ghi \n
|
wer \n
dfr \n
|

output should be (it find pipe and before that it replace new line to $$ and remove pipe)
first line -------abc$$def$$ghi
second line-----wer$$dfr

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{printf "%s$$",$0} END {print ""}'

sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/$$/g'
```

See this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/391360/remove-line-break-using-awk) as well.